# Connection between Eclipse and Android virtual device on two computers

Tags: android, eclipse, networking, adb, android-virtual-device

I would like to make a connection between Eclipse which runs on my PC with Android Virtual Device which is on another PC. Both computers are on the same home network (LAN). Is it possible somehow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418555/connect-eclipse-to-android-emulator-on-a-different-machine

Comment: @ViVekH Thank you. I couldn't find the answer here :)